# There's no space between the first two rows of a bootstrap grid

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Basically I'm coding a footer for which I've done a grid/table using Bootstrap 4. Anyway, because of some reason, there's no spacing between the first and the second row of the grid. On the other hand, there IS spacing between all the other columns.
Could someone please help me? Here's the Codepen:
https://codepen.io/rooiboQuality/pen/oNgdyPY

HTML:

```
<footer>

    <div class="footer-text">

        <div class="footer-main container-fluid">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm">
                    <p>Specialer</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm"></div>
                <div class="col-sm"></div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <p>Kontakt</p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Akupunktur</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Ansigtsmassage</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><a href="mailto:kontakt@sjaeloglegme.dk">kontakt@sjaeloglegeme.dk</a></div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Piskesmældsbehandling</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Hovedbundsmassage</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Kinesiotape</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><p>Telefon: +45 41 42 41 08</p></div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Migræner</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Manuel terapi</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><p>Lene Haus Vej 21 st. tv</p></div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Bindevævsmassage</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><a href="#">Medicinsk akupunktur</a></div>
                <div class="col-sm"><p>CVR: 33690193</p></div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="footer-info container-fluid">

            <p>Sjæl og Legeme Helsepartner V/ Jens Erik Pedersen  |  Lene Haus Vej 21 1. sal tv.  |  7430  |  Ikast  |  Tlf. 41 42 41 08  |  kontakt@sjaeloglegeme.dk</p>

        </div>

    </div>

    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QcsqrzG/man.png" alt="man">

</footer>
```

CSS (+ Bootstrap):

```
    footer {
    padding: 60px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.footer-text {
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
}

footer img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 20%;
}

footer .container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

footer p, footer a {
    color: #BFBFBF;
}

footer .row:nth-child(1) .col-sm p {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #fff;
}

.footer-info {
    margin-top: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is `margin-bottom: 1rem;` for `<p>` tag which you're using in all the other rows except for the first row. That's why there is spacing between all other rows.

You can provide a margin to `<a>` as well as `<p>` in your css to override default styles.

```
footer p, footer a {
    display:block; //making anchor block element otherwise it won't take margin 
    margin: 1em 0;
    color: #BFBFBF;
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should I add '1em' to the margin or '1rem'?